# Converting JSON to CSV in C++

Tags: c++, json, excel, csv

I'm trying to convert JSON arrays to CSV files in C++ and I'm curious what the method should be.

Let's say I have a JSON array that looks like this:

```
[["Bcode","firstname","lastname"],
["11234","richard","nixon"]]
```

and I want to convert it to a .csv that, (as I understand it) would be

```
Bcode,firstname,lastname,
11234,richard,nixon
```

The JSON array I'm getting seems to already have a line break in it, so can I just delete all the quotation marks and brackets and have it be a workable CSV file?

Alternately, is there any file extension that I can save JSON arrays to that can be read by MSExcel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to remove the quote marks -- CSV can (and frequently does) include them. They're necessary anytime you might want to include a comma inside a field (e.g., if you had a "name" field instead of `firstname` and `lastname` as separate fields, the value might be: "Nixon, Richard". If you delete the quotes, it'll no longer look like a single field.

You do want to delete the comma at the end of the line.

I would also consider any field that includes an embedded quote. If memory serves, JSON uses `\"` to signal a quote inside a field. CSV uses `""`, so unless your data doesn't/won't include any embedded quotes, you may need to deal with replacing `\"` with `""` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Formally speaking, JSON string may contain escape characters, e.g. "\n", "\u20AC".

To handle all these cases, you will need a JSON parser to parse a JSON text.

In your application, it is possible to use a SAX style (event-based) API, i.e. Scan through the JSON file from begin to end, without generating a intermediate DOM (Document Object Model).

You may check [rapidjson](http://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/), which supports SAX style API.

You may write a CSV writer, referring to $rapidjson::Writer$, to output CSV string from events. The code will look like this:

```
CsvWriter writer(outputStream);
rapidjson::Reader reader;
reader.Parse<0>(inputStream, writer);
```

Then, the reader will call the member functions of writer during parsing the input stream. In your example, it will call the functions in this order:

```
writer.StartArray();
writer.StartArray();
writer.String("Bcode", 5, true);
writer.String("firstname", 9, true);
writer.String("lastname", 8, true);
writer.EndArray();
writer.StartArray();
writer.String("11234", 5, true);
writer.String("richard", 7, true);
writer.String("nixon", 5, true);
writer.EndArray();
writer.EndArray();
```

The second parameter of String() is the length of string. The third parameter indicates whether you should duplicate the string.

It should be easy to write out your own CSV format with these function calls.

Finally, it is noted that, using SAX style API will need much less memory consumption, but the handler may be more difficult to write than the DOM version. rapidjson supports both SAX and DOM style API at your choice.